# When to use Long vs long in java?

Tags: java, dictionary, constructor

Below is my Interface -

```
public interface IDBClient {
    public String read(ClientInput input);
}
```

This is my Implementation of the Interface -

```
public class DatabaseClient implements IDBClient {

    @Override
    public String read(ClientInput input) {

    }
}
```

Now I have a factory which gets the instance of `DatabaseClient` like this -

```
IDBClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.getInstance();
....
```

Now I need to make a call to `read` method of my `DatabaseClient` which accepts the `ClientInput` parameter and below is the class for the same. This class was not written by me so that is the reason I am having a question on this and I am pretty much sure this is the wrong way of doing it.

```
public final class ClientInput {

    private Long userid;
    private Long clientid;
    private Long timeout_ms = 20L;
    private boolean debug;
    private Map<String, String> parameterMap;

    public ClientInput(Long userid, Long clientid, Map<String, String> parameterMap, Long timeout_ms, boolean debug) {
        this.userid = userid;
        this.clientid = clientid;
        this.parameterMap = parameterMap;
        this.timeout_ms = timeout_ms;
        this.debug = debug;
    }
}
```

So when customer make a call to `read` method of `DatabaseClient`, they will create the `ClientInput` parameter like this and then use the factory to get the Instance of `DatabaseClient` and then call the read method accordingly.

```
Map<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
paramMap.put("attribute", "segmentation");

ClientInput input = new ClientInput(109739281L, 20L, paramMap, 1000L, true);

IDBClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.getInstance();
client.read(input);
```

**Problem Statement:-**

1. So my first question is does the `userid`, `clientid`, `timeout_ms` should be `Long` object or just simply `long` in `ClientInput` class?
2. Second question I have is, it might be possible that customer can pass wrong information such as `negative user ids`, `negative client id`, `negative timeout` value etc etc.. Then where I should do this validation? Should I do this validation check in the constructor of `ClientInput` class or at some other place? What's the better way of doing this and how should I do the validation?

Comment: You have asked two very different questions. You should have made two seperate postings, as Stackoverflow is not meant to be a discussion group. I'm pretty sure you would find both questions asked and answered many times before. On the first question, search for when to use object and when to use a primitive. For the second question, search for validation of arguments / parameters.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I don't think there's a single correct answer. A few suggestions:

- The biggest difference I see between `long` and `Long` in this context is that `Long` may be `null`. If there's a possibility you might have missing values, the `Long` object will be helpful as `null` can indicate missing values. If you're using primitives, you'll have to use some special value to indicate missing, which is probably going to be a mess. Speed or size is not likely to be an  issue unless you're planning on making an array of a million of these things and then serializing.
- My preference for validation logic is to throw some sort of custom `ValidationException` at the point at which the thing could fail. If you're just creating these things with a constructor, the simplest thing would be just to validate there, e.g.

  ```
   public ClientInput(Long userid, Long clientid, Map<String, String> parameterMap, Long timeout_ms, boolean debug) throws ValidationException {          

        if (userid == null) throw new ValidationException("UserId is required"); 
              ...etc, etc...
  }
  ```

Ultimately, the `ValidationException` is only useful if you can catch it at a point where you can do something useful with it - echo it back to a user or whatever.

Comment: I do the same Steve, only I use IllegalArgumentException. But yes, Long is a wrapper for a long. The only real advantage to using Long is for equating reference instead of value, or using null as some special sentinel.

Answer (score 88):

`long` is a primitive, which *must* have a value. Simple.

`Long` is an *object*, so:

- it can be `null` (meaning whatever you like, but "unknown" is a common interpretation)
- it can be passed to a method that accepts an `Object`, `Number`, `Long` or `long` parameter (the last one thanks to auto-unboxing)
- it can be used as a generic parameter type, ie `List<Long>` is OK, but `List<long>` is **not** OK
- it can be serialized/deserialized via the java serialization mechanism

Always use the simplest thing that works, so if you need any of the features of `Long`, use `Long` otherwise use `long`. The overhead of a `Long` is surprisingly small, but it is there.

Answer (score 4):

1  Long is the object orientated counter part of long. The difference is as follows, and it applies to Float to float, Integer to integer etc.

- long is a primitive type, while Long is a Java class (and so it will inherit Object).
- long must be assigned with a valid number, while Long can be null
- long instances can't use the benefits of OO, while instances of Long are real Java objects
- Long is a serializable so it will be very useful when doing file, database or network IO
- long is more efficient than Long considering memory space and processing speed

If you are doing heavy calculations, use primitive types. Otherwise if you're concerning more about design, the object counter parts will be very useful.

2  Since you are not using any frameworks if I'm observing correctly, I suggest you make an interface like **Validated** with a method *bool validate()*. And every time you try to put a input into the database call validate in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1) Use Long if you need to treat the value as an object. Use long otherwise; it's more efficient.

2) Judgement call, really. Putting it deeper means you're going to check even when the value is coming from a source you trust, but that may catch errors in other code. Putting it closer to the user input means you lose that deep sanity-check (and may need to check in more than one place) but avoids spending time checking things you've already checked. What's best depends on how you plan on using/enhancing this code in the future.

Answer (score 1):

1. As `Long` is wrapper class privimitive type `long` and `Long` is a class, which indicate its instance could be null. In my perspective use wrapper class is better than primitive type because there could have `null` state in it, which could tells us more information.
   In addition, wrapper class will automatically initialized with 0, it is good for lazy using.
2. For data validation, I think you'd better do it in `controller` rather than `DAO`, then have a good method to handle this or alert user to modify them!

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of the Long class is that the value can be null. In your case, if no Long ID is supplied, if you quickly detect this with something like..

```
public ClientInput(Long userid, Long clientid, Map<String, String> parameterMap, Long timeout_ms, boolean debug) {
    if (userid == null) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("userid is null");
    }
```

To your second question, you could place your ID validation in the constructor as well. This ensures that if the ID is null or invalid, a ClientInput can never be created.  But there is no "best" answer for where you put this validation, it depends on the structure of the rest of your code, but ideally you want to catch such things as early as possible.

```
public ClientInput(Long userid, Long clientid, Map<String, String> parameterMap, Long timeout_ms, boolean debug) {
    if (userid == null || userid < USER_ID_MIN || userid > USER_ID_MAX ) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("userid is invalid");
    }
```

Another option is to accept the userid parameter as a Long, testing it for null, but then store it as a private, primitive long, once you know its valid.

Answer (score 0):

I try to keep Bean objects as simple as possible, which would mean handling validation elsewhere - either in a separate Validator class or in a validate() method. The general algorithm is the same:

- validateInputParametres()
- readDb()

I would do something like:

```
final ClientInput input = new ClientInput(109739281L, 20L, paramMap, 1000L, true);
validate(input); // throw/handle exceptions here

final Map<String, String> paramMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
paramMap.put("attribute", "segmentation");

final IDBClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.getInstance();
client.read(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

People forgot to mention that `long` cannot be used in logical comparison because its contains string in it, simple logical conditions wont work like `==` ,`!=` , `>`, `<` to do this you have to use `compareTo()` function that comes with `Long` object class.