# Why is implicit conversion from int to Long not possible?

Tags: java

I can implicitly conver int to long and long to Long. Why is it not possible to implicitly convert int to Long? Why can't Java do the implicit conversion on the last line of the example?

```
int i = 10; //OK
long primitiveLong = i;  //OK
Long boxedLong = primitiveLong;  //OK
boxedLong = i; //Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Long
```

Comment: That's because auto boxing has a 1 to 1 relationship from its `Object` to its primitive type.

Comment: probably no real reason except that the language designers decided not to support that.  you can make it work with `boxedLong = (long)i`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Long` and `Integer` are objects. Boxing/unboxing only works with primitives.
Doing `Long boxedLong = i` is like `Long boxedLong = new Integer(10)`, that's a no no !
Plus, remember that there is no inheritance between `Long` and `Integer` so even `Integer i = new Long()` is not valid

Comment: @CachoSanta In this context, objects mean classes implicitly ;).

Answer (score 1):

Boxing only works with primitives. That's why.

Try this: `Long.valueOf(int);`

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf%28long%29)

Answer (score 1):

> the biggest difference I see between long and Long in this context is that Long may be null. If there's a possibility you might have missing values the Long object will be helpful as the null can indicate missing values. If you're using primitives you'll have to use some special value to indicate missing, which is probably going to be a mess. Speed or size is not likely to be an issue unless you're planning on making an array of a million of these things and then serializing.  ([When to use Long vs long in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034955/when-to-use-long-vs-long-in-java))

In truth, there is no practical reason. Except that `int` is a primitive, `long` is a primitive, but `Long` is not.

I suggest you use `Long.valueOf()`

So like this:

```
Long longValue = Long.valueOf(InsertIntHere);
```