# 406 Not Acceptacle error while hitting REST API from postman

Tags: java, rest, api, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I had a getMapping API which always responding 406 Not acceptable error.

```java
@GetMapping(path="/check/{userId}", produces="text/plain")
public @ResponseBody Long check(@PathVariable("userId") String userId) {
    return (long) 22;
}
```

EndPoint which I am hitting from postman,

```
localhost:8080/api/check/0003az
```

with header,

```
Content-Type : "application/json"
Accept : "text/plain"
```

from postman, and getting response as `406 Not Acceptable`

Is there anything which Im missing here?

Comment: did you mean `localhost:8080/check/0003az` in `@GetMapping` you don't have `api` unless you mention it in to of controller

Comment: 406 not acceptable is your client agent asking the server to accept headers and it’s unable to do so. Take a look at your Accept header, that MIME type, is it authorized by the server?

Comment: @YCF_L I had `/api` as common

Comment: @EvOlaNdLuPiZ I am passing Accept heade

Answer (score 0):

406 Not Acceptable it means you are doing something wrong with return type.

Please go through [this](https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/406-not-acceptable) link and change your return (long) 22; to string or remove Accept: "text/plain"

Answer (score 0):

Mind the [difference between Long and long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034955/when-to-use-long-vs-long-in-java), as you are using `Long` as the return type and cast that to `long`.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am using `produces="text/plain"` and trying to return `Long` I got this error. After changing the return type to `String` and converted `Long` result to `String` while returning error got fixed.